# Programmatically opening IE from Chrome (or other browsers)

Tags: html, sqlite, internet-explorer, google-chrome, activex

We are trying migrate our web apps (healthcare) to HTML5 and are pretty excited about the SQLite features in Chrome.  One of our apps requires an ActiveX component (a proprietary wysiwyg editor) which means we have to use IE.  However, we also have hit a roadblock in that we are not sure if IE can support local storage like Chrome.

Could anyone help with some pointers?

Alternatively, we are considering retaining the main apps in non-IE browsers, but just have the wysiwyg editor open up as a separate browser window but in IE.  Simply put, if I click a button in Chrome (or other non-IE browsers), is it possible to programmatically open a new window on Internet Explorer?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why coding to standards, and no one browser, is so important.

Comment: IE WebStorage docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197062(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Not possible without a browser plugin.

Main app in Chrome, with WSIWYG editor in IE? sounds like a horrible idea.

Comment: Doubt it's doable with an extension; I reckon it'd need a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer: Use a non-proprietary WYSIWYG editor.

[There's](https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg) [plenty](http://www.openwebware.com/) [to](http://ckeditor.com/demo) [be](http://nicedit.com/index.php) [found](http://www.tinymce.com/index.php) [out there](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/examples/).

Comment: The only thing I have to offer to you, then, is my condolence.

Answer (score -1):

Not possible to directly call another executable from browser environment, there will be big security issues.

You could either install a browser plugin or add a registry to achieve this.

Simplest solution would be adding **a URI scheme for IE**, and links in format `ie:http://example.com` will launch IE and visit `http://example.com`.

To add a URI scheme for IE, add
[this registry](https://superuser.com/a/1437844/210250):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie]
"URL Protocol"=""
@="URL:IE Protocol"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /c set url=\"%1\" & call set url=%%url:ie:=%% & call start iexplore -nosessionmerging -noframemerging %%url%%"
```

Some important notes:

1. **You have to wrap `%1` in double quotes.** Otherwise url with multiple params like `example.com?a=1&b=2` will be stripped to `example.com?a=1`, params after `&` will be ignored.
2. **You have to remove the double quotes when calling `iexplore`**. If you don't remove the double quotes and open multiple IE window from chrome, only the first IE window will get the correct URL. But removing quotes with command `set url=%%url:\"=%%` or `set url=%%url:~1,-1%%` doesn't work.
3. **If you just can't make it to remove those quotes, add switches `-nosessionmerging` and `-noframemerging` to `iexplore`.** These are [command-line options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/hh826025(v=vs.85)) to control "merging" behavior for IE.